# Update UI-Thread from a Android-AsyncTask in a while-loop

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I am using a while-loop in an AsyncTask. The program is awaiting socket-request like

```
while(true) {
  in = readLine();
...
}
```

How I can update the main UI from this loop of the AsyncTask. Normally it's forbidden to update the main thread, and to do it in `doPostExecute` does not solve the problem, because then I have to leave the while-loop.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen tutorials on Android socket programming in some places. I do not think they used an AsyncTask, but rather a Thread or Service, I think

Answer (score 0):

*One way* to accomplish this, could be to call `publishProgress(object)` somewhere in your loop. This, in turn, calls the method `onProgressUpdate(Object[])`
in which you can update views in the main thread.

In my example below, mTextView is a member variable of the class in which the AsyncTask resides. E.g.

```
public class NewtworkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        ....
    }

    private class MySyncTask extends AsyncTask {
        ....
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            ....
            while (true) {
                while ((lineFromServer = mFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    Object object[] = { lineFromServer };
                    publishProgress(object);
                }
             }
        }

        ....

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if (values.length > 0) {
                mTextView.append(values[0]+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
}
```